# fetch a div tag from return jquery ajax return value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got ajax working that returns whole HTML page.

I need to fetch a div tag which the class name is 'thisclass', this is a unique css class on that page.

I managed to use .find(), but then the string turned into object, how to solve this?

```
$.ajax({
      'url': '/test/',
      'type': 'POST',
      'data': {'age': age},
      'dataType': 'html',
      'success': function(data) {
       // data contains a whole page of HTML, I need the contents of a div tag
          which has css class .thisclass
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,

```
$.ajax({
      'url': '/test/',
      'type': 'POST',
      'data': {'age': age},
      'dataType': 'html',
      'success': function(data) {
                        $("#yourid").html($(".thisclass",$(data)).html());
                 }
});
```

Comment: $(".thisclass",$(data)).html() does not return anything, an empty string

Comment: You have element with class thisclass in your response?

Comment: $(".thisclass", $(data)) works(in console, I see the element returns), but not as html. Then I jumped to the third one, which returns nothing.

Comment: That's kind of bizarre! Again, if you put it in a jsFiddle we could probably debug better. But, hmm, maybe jQuery doesn't want to let you use `.html()` on elements that aren't inserted into the DOM yet? What are you trying to do with the element, anyway---could you just call `$(".thisclass", $(data)).appendTo("#someElement")` maybe?

Comment: Also try `$(".thisclass", $(data)).appendTo("body").html()` to test if jQuery wants the element inserted into the DOM before `.html()` will work, and `$(".thisclass", $(data))[0].innerHTML` to see if maybe jQuery is messing up but the native browser `innerHTML` property instead works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `.html()` on the object you got with `.find()`.

Alternately, if you can manage to use an `id="thisId"` instead of a `class="thisclass"`, then jQuery's [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method has some special abilities, that would allow you do do something like

```
$("#placeToPutTheResult").load("http://example.com/page #thisId");
```

Comment: What output do you get from the console when you use `find`?

Comment: Same issue with other answer. I can find the element, but just can't get html contents using html().